# ChaplinJS. Organize interaction between views and controller

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, chaplinjs

There is a controller (ObjectController) with action "list". Controller creates and loads collection, creates view, ObjectsPageView, and render it. ObjectsPageView consists of 3 subviews: ObjectListView, SearchFormView and PaginationView. I do not know how to organize interaction between views and controller.
Now I only have 2 options:

1. Add parameter "page" for links in PaginationView. Then, when you click on the page link, the Layout will redirect to ObjectController with new parameters. In the SearchFormView listen submit event, and on submit, SearchFormView itself will redirect to ObjectController with new parameters.
2. In PaginationView and SearchFormView trigger custom events (paginationLinkClicked, searchFormSubmitted) and listen to them in controller. When event occurs, change current url, reload collection, and views will be redrawn.

Which option is better? Is there the better way?

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the best, but you should have just one view (ObjectListView), pagination and search are actions defined on the controller, in that actions call to API, with specific parameters, that provide the data (JSON) then you render ObjectListView with the new model

I hope be more clear.